# Mirror Gitlab Repository

Tags: gitlab, mirror, aws-codecommit

I have a mirror between Gitlab and AWS CodeCommit. I have environment variables on Gitlab to store passwords. Is there some way to mirror these environment variables in CodeCommit?

The direction is from Gitlab to CodeCommit.

Comment: Can you clarify which direction the mirror is going in? GitLab to AWS or AWS to GitLab? Or bidirectional?

Comment: Oh yes, the direction is from Gitlab to CodeCommit.